# How many solutions does the equation have $x_1 + x_2 +x_3 = 8$ have with restrictions $x_1 \leq 2$ and $x_2 \leq 3$ (for all nonnegative numbers)

Tags: inequality

How many solutions does the equation have $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 8$ have with restrictions $x_1 \leq 2$ and $x_2 \leq 3$ (for all nonnegative numbers)?

I seem to be stuck on the multiple conditions that are $\leq$

Comment: With no restrictions at all (just nonnegative numbers) my answer is 45.  Then I tried to subtract from that where x1 >= 3 and x2 >= 4 but didn't arrive at correct answer

Comment: Three choices for $x_1$, four for $x_2$, in each case $x_3$ accommodates the positive difference.

Comment: Ah, 12 it is then.

Answer (score 1):

We have $x_1 \le 2$ and $x_2 \le 3 \Rightarrow x_3 = 8 - x_2 - x_1 \ge 0$.

So each solution will be of the form $(x_1, \, x_2, \, 8 - x_2 - x_1)$.

There are $3$ choices for $x_1$ and $4$ choices for $x_2$, hence a total of $3 \times 4 = 12$ solutions.

Answer (score 0):

A general method to tackle this problem:

Look at the complement. The complement consists of $x_1>2$ **OR** $x_2 >3$. You seem to have taken $x_1>2$ AND $x_2 >3$.